# How can I find the last moving average crossover price x candle before in mql4?

Tags: mql4, mql5

I want to code a  function which will return the price of the last moving average crossover.  I will be really happy if anyone here helps me to achive this in mql4 code..

Answer (score -1):

```
    int manyCandles=1000, crossOverCandle;
    double theOpenPrice;
    for(int lastCandle=1; lastCandle<manyCandles; lastCandle++){
       crossOverCandle=0;
       double firstMA = iMA(_Symbol,_Period,maPeriod,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,lastCandle);
       double secondMA = iMA(_Symbol,_Period,maPeriod,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,lastCandle);
       double firstMAlast = iMA(_Symbol,_Period,maPeriod,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,lastCandle+1);
       double secondMAlast = iMA(_Symbol,_Period,maPeriod,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,lastCandle+1);
       
       if(secondMAlast>firstMAlast && secondMA<firstMA){
          theOpenPrice = Open[lastCandle];
          crossOverCandle = lastCandle;
          Break;
       }
}
Comment("The last cross over happened on ",lastCandle," candle, the price was ",theOpenPrice);
```

You can try the above code.